# How to get the current custom post's term name

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type with custom taxonomies, and want to display the current post's term name in a div.

In each post I'm only selecting 1 term, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found the answer. Spent one hour searching and finally found the solution in 5 minutes. This is my code:

```
<?php 
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'tipo-de-cursos', array("fields" => "names"));
echo $term_list[0]; 
?>
```